# TakeLast not working as expected in .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, .net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.1

I have written the below code in the .net core 3.1 console application. It's not working as expected.

```
var arr = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 10));
var last5 = arr.TakeLast(5);
foreach (var i in last5)
    Console.WriteLine(i); //writing 6 7 8 9 10
arr.AddRange(new[] { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 });
foreach (var i in last5)
    Console.WriteLine(i); //writing 6 7 8 9 10 11
```

It is working as expected (6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15) If I target the project to in .net core 2.2.

I have used `for` loop for time being to solve the issue.

Why is it giving different values in .net core 2.2 and 3.1?

Comment: Which result are you expect?

Comment: It’s pretty clear in the question. It’s working in 2.2 but not working in 3.1

Comment: I wouldn't say, that's your result the expected one. However, you can examine [`TakeLastEnumerableFactory<TSource>`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/6072e4d3a7a2a1493f514cdf4be75a3d56580e84/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Take.SpeedOpt.cs#L16) and check what happens

Comment: My question is very simple. Why is it giving different values in .net core 2.2 and 3.1

Comment: Very curious. Looks like a bug.

Comment: It has been entered as a bug 2 days ago: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/39864 apparently because of https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/36051

Comment: Why do you ask it here when you also asked it where such questions belong? (Or at least *saw* it asked there). Stack Overflow can do notoriously little about issues in library software. We can't fix them.

Comment: @GertArnold you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few observations here:

1. Calling `ToList()` after initial call to `TakeLast(5)` fixes the issue.
2. Calling arr.TakeLast(5) after `arr.AddRange` also fixes the issue.

I assume it's a bug that is related to the returned iterator by `TakeLast.`

In one case(version 2.2), the iterator position is not resetting after the call for the `AddRange` method. In another(3.1), it's resetting the array start.

Very strange behavior, xD.

Comment: Yes it’s a bug.